# Selenium. Unable to connect to the remote server error

Tags: c#, selenium

I am trying to use Selenium with C# and have the following problem.
Here is my code:

```
ISelenium sel = new DefaultSelenium("localhost", 4444, "*chrome", "http://facebook.com");
sel.Start();
```

In the second line I have this error:

```
System.Net.WebException : Unable to connect to the remote server
```

I don't know why it is happening. It should be something basic and easy.
I have seen the same question on stackoverflow, but it is 5 years old, so i don't think that the answer is right.

Comment: Try to use IP address instead of localhost. I didn't used selenium and I'm not sure if this is the problem. p.s. I used WatiN several times and it worked good you can try it too.

Comment: are you going thru a Proxy server by chance..? if so change localhost and replace it with the proxy name

Comment: First thing comes to mind: why aren't you using Selenium WebDriver? Selenium RC is old and deprecated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the late reply.

@MetodMan was right.

> are you going thru a Proxy server by chance..? if so change localhost and replace it with the proxy name